# Python main thread interruption

Tags: python, multithreading, keyboardinterrupt

Can anyone explain how the interrupt_main() method works in Python?

I've got this piece of Python code :

```
import time, thread

def f():
    time.sleep(5)
    thread.interrupt_main()

def g():
    thread.start_new_thread(f, ())
    time.sleep(10)
print time.time()
try:
    g()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print time.time()
```

And when I try to run it, it gives me the following output :

```
1380542215.5
# ... 10 seconds break...
1380542225.51
```

However, if I interrupt the program manually (CTRL-C), the thread is interrupted correctly :

```
1380542357.58
^C1380542361.49
```

Why does the thread interruption only occur after 10 seconds (and not 5) in the first example?

I found an [ancient thread n Python mailing list](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2004-November/293653.html), but it explains nearly nothing.

Comment: KeyboardInterrupt means you are interrupted by a keyboard.

Comment: Both work as expected. What's your problem?

Comment: I'd expect the main thread to be interrupted immediately (after 5 seconds).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`raise KeyboardInterrupt` does not interrupt a `time.sleep()`. The former is handled entirely inside the python interpreter, the latter invokes an operating system function.

So, in your case, the keyboard interrupt was handled, but only when `time.sleep()` completed its system call.

Try this instead:

```
def g():
    thread.start_new_thread(f, ())
    for _ in range(10): 
        time.sleep(1)
```